# mypy and lambda quit()

Tags: python, mypy

I have this problem with mypy under python 3.88 and w7, am I the only one?

```
x = lambda: quit()
print(1) # ok

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(2)  # Mypy: Statement is unreachable
```

You should use the mypy option --warn-unreachable to see the error.
To be more clear: print(2) is evaluated by Python but for mypy it is unreachable. Someone can explain to me why? Or it is a mypy bug?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mypy, but yes, looks like a bug to me. I can [reproduce it](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&flags=warn-unreachable&gist=a63b9675aa3c7c12bea61156f9931180). If you remove the `()` after `quit`, then it doesn't complain anymore, even though that doesn't change the reachability.

Comment: Also if you put the quit() in a def, seems a mypy error with lambda

Comment: It's interesting that it complains about the `print` but not about the `if`.

Comment: I will add an issue to mypy github.